# header not being set in storage promise

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to add a header to my api call however, i need to get auth token and set that to the header. But when i try and run the bellow code it doesn't set it, only sets the Content-Type.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class DataProvider {
  public token:string;

constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) {}

getsomething(){

 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
   this.token = val;
   console.log(this.token);
   headers = headers.set('AuthToken', this.token);
 });

 console.log(headers);

 return this.http.get('http://localhost:54951/getfarms', {
   headers: headers
 });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Observable.flatMap as in below example

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) { }

  getsomething() {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token')).flatMap((token) => {
      console.log(token);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers = headers.set('AuthToken', token);
      console.log(headers);

      return this.http.get('http://localhost:54951/getfarms', {
        headers: headers
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **header.set()** function does not return a header instance so do the following

```
headers = header.set('AuthToken', this.token); //change the line
headers.set('AuthToken', this.token); //do not reassign the headers object
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? The code seems to suggest that `set` return a new cloned object each time, if you just call set and you do nothing with the result it has no effect https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/72c7b6edea39f6591463c2a22eb24d087fd756b7/packages/common/http/src/headers.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the value you set in `this.storage.get('token').then` right after the call to `then`. The promise will not execute the handler immediately, since it is an async operation.

```
getsomething() {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
        this.token = val;
        console.log(this.token);
        headers = headers.set('AuthToken', this.token);


        console.log(headers);

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:54951/getfarms', {
            headers: headers
        });
    });
}
```

Or using async/await

```
async getsomethingAsync() {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let val = await this.storage.get('token')
    this.token = val;
    console.log(this.token);
    headers = headers.set('AuthToken', this.token);


    console.log(headers);

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:54951/getfarms', {
        headers: headers
    });
}
```